# Coherence Distributed Scheme for Specific Machine Distribution

Tags: configuration, oracle-coherence

Assume that machine1, machine 2 and machine 3 are on the same coherence cluster.

Is there a way that I can say that, in a cluster, I want my cache to be placed under machine1 and machine2 but not machine 3? And is there any disadvantages on this structure(network issues, performance etc)?

Thanks.

EDIT: I do not want any storage disabled nodes. Each node can store data but I want them to choose the cache data which they want to store. For ex:
Cache1: M1 OK, M2 OK, M3 NOK,
Cache2: M1 NOK, M2 OK, M3 OK  etc

Answer (score 1):

What we have done in our Coherence cluster, is to launch the JVMs that we do not want to be used as "cache nodes with the the property `-Dtangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage=false` set on the command line.  This allows those JVMs to join the cluster and access the cache as first-class cluster members, but they are not actually part of the cache.

So, in your example, all the JVMs on machine 3 specify the `tangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage` property as `false`, and machines 1 and 2, if run with this property set `true` (or without this property, it defaults to `true`), will be used as the cache servers.

**Edit:**

I don't know of a specific way to implement your updated question.  You could try providing a different coherence-cache-config.xml for each machine (so that each machine "sees" a different set of caches), but [this page](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/Cache+Configuration+Elements) seems to indicate that is not well supported.  I wish I had a better answer.